# Error importing Tensorflow on Mac 10.14.6 - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, tensorflow, keras

I've installed Tensorflow using pip on my Mac Mojave, but when I run a python program with
`import tensorflow as tf` and `from tensorflow import keras`it gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 114
    def TFE_ContextOptionsSetAsync(arg1, async):
                                         ^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

python version: 3.11

Comment: You installed somehow a version of tensorflow that is not supported by that version of python.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
pip install tensorflow-macos
```